# Initializer error in Camera App for Xcode in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, avfoundation

I am building an app similar to a camera app in Xcode 10.1 using Swift. To do this, I have imported AVFoundation, and am close to finishing my code. However, upon this line of code

```
     let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
```

which is in this block of code

```
func beginSession () {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput( device: captureDevice!)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
        self.previewLayer = self.previewLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }
```

There appears an error that reads "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' with an argument list of type '(session: AVCaptureSession, () -> ())'"

I don't exactly know what this means or how to fix it as I am relatively new to programming.

Comment: The opening  `{` at the end of the line is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you initialized captureSession?

Try something like this in your UIViewController:

```
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        beginSession()
    }

    func beginSession() {

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) {

            do {
                // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

                // Set the input device on the capture session.
                captureSession.addInput(input)

                // Initialize a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
                let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
                dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

                dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

                if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
                }

                // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.bounds // It may be best to setup an UIView outlet instead of using self.view
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!) 

                // Start video capture.
                captureSession.startRunning()

            } catch {
                // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Glad i can help :)